# Docker-compose .env file internal variable substitution

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables

I am trying to perform variable substitution inside of a `.env` file but have not had any luck so far.

I've been looking though the docker-compose documentation and have not found anything mentioning this (or any examples online) but it seems like something that would be surprising if not possible.

What I am talking about is doing something like this in my .env file:

```
// .env
SOME_LOCATION=/path/to/some/location

CONFIG_FILE=${SOME_LOCATION}/config
CONSTANT_FILE=${SOME_LOCATION}/constants
```

(This example makes `CONFIG_FILE` equal to the string `$${SOME_LOCATION}/config` and same thing happens with `CONSTANT_FILE`)

I realize that this is possible inside of the `compose.yml` file with syntax like this but can it be done just inside the `.env` file?

I'm using docker-compose version 1.24.1 if it's not possible then I will just copy past these kinds of things but it always feels dirty copying the same values through your configuration.

Comment: Short answer : you can't substitute variables inside a .env file.

Comment: It works with a recent version of docker-compose (1.29.1).

Answer (score 0):

You can change or add .env variable with *export* command in shell scripting.

File path like this;

```
-project
  -> docker-compose.yml
  -> .env
  -> start.sh
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  jira:
    image: atlassian/jira-software
    volumes:
      - ${CONFIG_FILE}:/var/atlassian/application-data/jira
    ports:
      - 8080:8080 
volumes:
  jira_vol:
    external: false
```

### start.sh

```
export "CONFIG_FILE=${SOME_LOCATION}/jira_vol"
docker-compose up -d
```

### .env

```
SOME_LOCATION=./volumes
```

Finally run this command;

```
sh start.sh
```

start.sh file will add CONFIG_FILE variable and run docker compose. And you can use CONFIG_FILE and SOME_LOCATION in *docker-compose.yml*.

Comment: Is there another way do to this that doesn't require setting them inside docker-compose? Is the only possible syntax of .env files `THIS=that`?